# reloading url from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval, window.location

I am working on the following code for a chrome extension. Basically I want it to check the page that initially loads and if it matches my website `st.mywebsite.com` it will execute the code. Right now it doesn't check and will execute any pages that loads. I am trying to get it to load `http://st.mywebsite.com/?q=` plus the terms in the array. So every X number of seconds/minutes it will load a new term in the array and add it to the url `http://st.mywebsite.com/?q=`can anyone help?

```
if((window.location.hostname != "st.mywebsite.com")){
    window.onload = function() {
        terms = new Array("5d65sd", "95sd4s", "h2j4g8h", "c87e2dd", "e6e5f2g4", "3m5g5gv");

        min = 1;//minimum
        max = 60;//maximum
        randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

        var seconds = randomnumber;
        var timer;

        function countdown() {
          var container = document.getElementById('right');
          seconds--;
          if(seconds > 0) {
            container.innerHTML = '<p>Please wait <b>'+seconds+'</b> seconds.</p>';
          } else {
            window.location = 'http://st.mywebsite.com/?q='+terms;
          }
        }

        timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you say this will be a chrome extension? Could you not define this behaviour in the manifest.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the line you have `window.location`, change it to `window.location.href`

Comment: how do i make it use one term at a time. it sends all terms at once

Comment: you can increment index because terms is an array. Some like that: `var index = 0; function countdown() { ... else { window.location.href = 'http://st.mywebsite.com/?q='+terms[index++] }}`.